# Accept a positive integer n as input and find the print the smallest integer that is divisible by all the integers in the range [1, n]

Tags: python

How do I solve this question? I've intuitively understood that I am required to find the LCM of the number between [1,n] but I cannot figure out how to code this without using the math library and function defining processes in Python. I did find some solutions for C++ but they are beyond my understanding.

Comment: why not math library? and what about numpy.lcm() ? and also first of all, [do a google search](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/lcm)

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @GhostOps, I did search for the LCM process. I do know how to compute for 2 numbers. I was finding difficulty in computing it for a range. The course instructor has asked us to focus on figuring out solutions without using libraries. I would've simply used the gcd function if permitted.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar I haven't figured a method out w/o the limitation that I've mentioned above but I did find something which helps solve this via the math library.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-number-divisible-first-n-numbers/

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply the numbers that are not a divisor of the other numbers

A simple (non optimal) algorithm is to descend the list of numbers and check if any smaller number is a divisor, if it is then add it to a blacklist.

Then multiply all numbers that are not blacklisted:

```
N = 10

number = 1
skip = set()
for i in range(N, 0, -1):
    for j in range(i-1, 1, -1):
        if j in skip:
            continue
        if not i%j:
            print(f'{j} divides {i}, skipping {j}')
            skip.add(j)
    if i not in skip:
        number *= i
```

output for N=10:

```
5 divides 10, skipping 5
2 divides 10, skipping 2
3 divides 9, skipping 3
4 divides 8, skipping 4
30240
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying.

Comment: I manually tried calculating the LCM for n=10 and got 5040 as the answer. Is there something wrong with your code or my calculation?

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest approach without any optimization would be sth like:

```
def int_div(n):
    outp = 0
    while(True):
        outp += 1 
        res_list = []
        for i in range(1,n+1): res_list.append(outp%i)
        if sum(res_list) == 0:
            break
    return outp
```

But it works well just for small numbers <=16.